# What is the difference between a quick scan and a full scan in HD Tune Pro?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hd-tune

A quick scan didn't find any error on my hard drive, whereas a full scan did. What is the difference between a quick scan and a full scan in HD Tune Pro? I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and HD Tune Pro 3.50.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [a manual](http://www.zsem.edu.pl/~dominikpres/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/hdtunepro.pdf) for HD Tune Pro.  On page 23 it describes the Error Scan.  It says the following:

> The Error Scan scans the entire disk surface for errors. Defects will show up as red blocks. The 
>   exact location of these defects are shown in the list below the graph.
>
> This test only performs read operations and is nondestructive.
>
> For a short test the quick scan option can be set. With this option enabled only certain parts 
>   across the disk surface will be tested.

So a full scan will scan every single block on the disk, and a quick scan will only scan some blocks on the disk.  The quick scan probably scans one block, then skips X blocks, then scans another block, then skips another X blocks, and so on.